# How can I redirect to another page with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

using js and html I want to click on a button for example 'login' and when I click it I want it to redirect me to an another page. How can I do that?

Comment: hi, check here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/14032355

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

- You can wrap the button with the `<a>` tag in case you want to use normal HTML
- Otherwise, you can use `window.location.href = 'redirect page`` for navigate with JavaScript

Comment: Anchor elements cannot have button elements as children.

Comment: yes I know that but when I click the button 'login' does not redirect me to the another page